# Detecting if a UITableViewCell is a reused cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I have UITableView cells with multiple buttons. 4 UIButtons per cell. For each UIButton I want to add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer. Code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FriendViewCell *cell = (FriendViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    for(int i =0; i<4; i++) {




            UIButton *button = cell.buttons[i];
            UILabel *label = cell.labels[i];

            [button setTag:(int)indexPath.row*4+i];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(friendTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressFriend:)];

            [button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

}

}
```

I just realised though that if a cell is reused then I am adding a gesture multiple times per button. Is there a way to detect if the cell created is reused or new? I don't think I can move the code to the FriendViewCell class because my gesture target friendTapped: is in my UITableViewController. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated! thanks

Comment: your code is incomplete, where to you create/alloc the cells?

Comment: Why not configure the tags and gesture recognizers in your storyboard (or nib file)?

Comment: @jlehr the number of buttons is dynamic and depends on the size of an array so they tags can't be configured in the storyboard. Right?

Comment: If the size of the array is dynamic, why is your `for` loop hardcoded to expect a count of 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way would be to create a custom class for your `Button`. This class would have an `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` created at initialization and a delegate (your controller) that will be called when the gesture is triggered.

**.h**

```
@class MyLongPressedButton
@protocol MyLongPressedButtonDelegate
- (void)buttonIsLongPressed:(MyLongPressedButton *)button;
@end

@interface MyLongPressedButton
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyLongPressedButtonDelegate > delegate
@end
```

**.m**

```
-(id)init {
   if (self = [super init]) {
     UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
     [self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

   }
   return self;
}

-(void)longPress:(id)sender {
   [_delegate buttonIsLongPressed:self]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are fast ways to solve this - you can check the existing gesture recognizers on the button whether there is a long press gesture recognizer.

A slightly better solution is to define a property on the cell, e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL recognizerAdded
```

However, the best solution is to do this inside the cell class

```
@implementation FriendViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
   //add the recognizers
}

@end
```

Note that you your table delegate shouldn't care about the structure of your cell, it's the cell's responsibility to setup itself properly.

Of course, you will need a delegate on the cell to notify you about the action but it will be a cleaner solution.

Comment: But if I do it in the cell I will get an error because the selector method is in my UITableViewController

Comment: @Kex That is the whole point of using delegate. The cell know that the button is clicked, and it'll pass the information to its delegate (viewController).
If you don't know what is, or how to do delegate, you can check this Apple Doc presentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend placing the code inside your cell and creating a delegate method that will return a reference to the cell.

E.g.

```
@protocol myAwesomebuttonCellDelegate <NSObject>

 - (void)myAwesomeCell:(MyAwesomeCell *)cell buttonPressed:(UIButton *)btn;

@end
```

Then in your view controller you can use:

```
NSIndexPath *index = [tblView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

to get the row / section